# How can I use a theme option in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, themes

I'm creating a Wordpress theme and have added an option which allowed users to change a font family using (simplified code):

```
update_option('mytheme_font', $_POST['mytheme_font']);
```

How do I then get the value of that option in a JS file of the theme? I need it because I'm using Cufon to replace some H1's and H2's. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could echo some thing like this in the `<head>` of the header.php

```
<?php 

$defaultThemeFont = "myDefaultValue";
$userThemeFont = get_option("mytheme_font");

if($defaultThemeFont == NULL)
    $userThemeFont = $defaultThemeFont
?>
<script>

<?php echo "var mytheme_font = $userThemeFont;"; ?>

</script>
```

Now you can access this variable from any JS file

Comment: I already thought of this, but is this the only possibility?
BTW people: don't forget to escape the single quotes: 
<?php echo str_replace("'", "\'", $userThemeFont); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have four options I suppose.

Output your javascript to your page inside script tags. Easiest

```
<script>
   <?php echo 'var x = 3;' ?>
</script>
```

Output the variable to your page and then read that from your javascript file. Clunky, but does mean you don't have to create some js globals.

```
<div id="x" style="display: none;">3</div>
var x = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML();
```

[Added] - Use AJAX to request the data and parse after page load.

Last and I don't recommend it, but setup php to parse `.js` files to dynamically produce javascript files. This way you could place a `<?php ?>` call in your .js files.

Comment: AJAX requests can be very slow, so it's also not the best option.